# Chrome, What happens when you emulate css print media?

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

When I turn on Chrome's emulation for css print media, and press CMD + P to print, the print preview looks correct.  i.e. it is in the format I want to print in.

When I turn off emulate css print media, and press CMD + P, the format gets messed up.

In order to start debugging this it would help to know what is actually happening when you emulate print.

Thanks!